# Matching word using Regular Expression in a string

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTable to display records and I want to search using RegExp in certain scenario
I am having string as:

```
var str="ATP ,Defib 30 J (830 V),Defib 30 J (830 V),Aborted Defib 30 J (830 V),Aborted CVRT 15 J (588 V)";
```

if I search using only CVRT, then It should not be matched, but if I searched using Aborted CVRT, it should be matched.
i.e. If I enter text starting after comma,text should be matched like searching with Aborted CVRT or Defib 30, Also should match ATP (first in string).

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should use two RegExs, one for the `Defib 30`, other for `ATP`.

Something like these two:

1. `,\w+ \w+`

Matches: `,Defib 30`, etc.

1. `^\w+`

Matches: `ATP`.

---

If you don't need that `,`, you can replicate positive look behind:

```
var matches = [], str = "ATP ,Defib 30 J (830 V),Defib 30 J (830 V),Aborted Defib 30 J (830 V),Aborted CVRT 15 J (588 V)";

str.replace(/(,)(\w+ \w+)?/g, function(match, $0, $1){
    if($0) matches.push($1)
});

console.log(matches); // ["Defib 30", "Defib 30", "Aborted Defib", "Aborted CVRT"]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use string ***.match()*** in javascript.The match() method searches a
>   string for a match against a regular expression, and returns the
>   matches, as an Array object.

```
var str = "ATP ,Defib 30 J (830 V),Defib 30 J (830 V),Aborted Defib 30 J (830 V),Aborted CVRT 15 J (588 V)"; 

var res = str.match(/CVRT/g);

console.log(res);
```